# Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.setCellValueFactory(javafx.util.Callback)" because "this.colName" is null

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception

so my problem is i cant display data to tableview, i cant figure it out why
i have a form use ProductController with display tableview method, in another controller CardProductContrller i call the method from ProductController in addFcn method and it return error :

Cannot invoke `javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.setCellValueFactory(javafx.util.Callback)` because `this.colName` is null

heres more detail error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.setCellValueFactory(javafx.util.Callback)" because "this.colName" is null
    at application.ProductController.showOrderDetail(ProductController.java:409)
    at application.CardProdController.addFcn(CardProdController.java:169)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:72)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:270)
    at javafx.fxml@21/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:84)
    at javafx.fxml@21/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1855)
    at javafx.fxml@21/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1726)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:232)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:189)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base@21/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@21/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8875)
    at javafx.controls@21/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls@21/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:207)
    at javafx.controls@21/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:232)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:189)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base@21/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@21/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3984)
    at javafx.graphics@21/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1890)
    at javafx.graphics@21/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2708)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
```

here the code :
cardProductController :

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

public class CardProdController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button addBtn;

    @FXML
    private BorderPane cardForm;

    @FXML
    private ImageView imageView;

    @FXML
    private Label name;

    @FXML
    private Label price;

    @FXML
    private Spinner<Integer> quantity;
    
    private productModel productM;
    
    private Image image;
    
    private String proId;
    private String pro_image;
    private String pro_date;
    
    private SpinnerValueFactory<Integer> spin;
    
    @FXML 
    private Connection connection;
    private PreparedStatement prepare;
    private ResultSet result;
    private Alert alert;

    private double pr;
    private int cusId;
    
    public void setData(productModel productM) {
        this.productM = productM;
        
        pro_image = productM.getProductImage();
        pro_date = String.valueOf(productM.getDate());
        proId = productM.getProductId();
        name.setText(productM.getProductName());
        price.setText(String.valueOf(productM.getProductPrice()));
        String path = "File:" + productM.getProductImage();
        image = new Image(path, 190, 130, false, true);
        imageView.setImage(image);
        pr = productM.getProductPrice();

    }
    
    private int qty;
    private double totalP;
    private String ordDID;
    public void addFcn() throws SQLException {
            ProductController pC = new ProductController();
            pC.customerID(); 
            pC.order_detailID();
            qty = quantity.getValue();
            String check = "";
            String checkAvailable = "SELECT pro_status FROM product WHERE pro_id = '" + proId + "'";
            
            connection = Database.connect();
            try {
                int checkS = 0;
                String checkStock = "SELECT pro_quantity FROM product WHERE pro_id = '" + proId + "'";

                prepare = connection.prepareStatement(checkStock);
                result = prepare.executeQuery();
                
                if(result.next()) {
                    checkS = result.getInt("pro_quantity");
                }      
                
                if(checkS == 0){
                    String updateStock = "UPDATE product SET pro_status = 'Unavailable' WHERE pro_id = '"+proId+"'";   
                    //update to database to mark it as unavailable
                    prepare = connection.prepareStatement(updateStock);
                    prepare.executeUpdate();
                }
                prepare = connection.prepareStatement(checkAvailable);
                result = prepare.executeQuery();

                if (result.next()) {
                    check = result.getString("pro_status");
                }
                if (!check.equals("Available") || qty == 0) {
                    alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
                    alert.setTitle("Error Message");
                    alert.setHeaderText(null);
                    alert.setContentText("Product currently unavalible or we run out");
                    alert.showAndWait();
                } else {
                    if (checkS < qty) {
                        alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
                        alert.setTitle("Error Message");
                        alert.setHeaderText(null);
                        alert.setContentText("Invalid. This product is Out of stock");
                        alert.showAndWait();
                    } else {
                        pro_image = pro_image.replace("\\", "\\\\");
                        
                        String insertData = "INSERT INTO order_detail "
                                + "(cus_id, ord_id, pro_id ,pro_name, pro_price, pro_quantity, orderDate) "
                                + "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                        prepare = connection.prepareStatement(insertData);
                        prepare.setString(1, String.valueOf(data.cusId));
                        
                        ordDID = data.ordDiD;
                        prepare.setString(2, ordDID);
                        prepare.setString(3, proId);
                        prepare.setString(4, name.getText());
                        
                        totalP = (qty * pr);
                        prepare.setString(5, String.valueOf(totalP));
                        prepare.setString(6, String.valueOf(qty));
                        
                        Date date = new Date();
                        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
                        prepare.setString(7, String.valueOf(sqlDate));
                        
                        prepare.executeUpdate();

                        int upStock = checkS - qty;

                        String updateStock = "UPDATE product SET pro_quantity = " + upStock + " WHERE pro_id = '"+proId+"'";
                        //update product to mark it's quantity as decreased as being order by customer 
                        prepare = connection.prepareStatement(updateStock);
                        prepare.executeUpdate();
                        
                        alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
                        alert.setTitle("Information Message");
                        alert.setHeaderText(null);
                        alert.setContentText("Successfully Added!");
                        Optional<ButtonType> option = alert.showAndWait();
                        
                        if(option.get().equals(ButtonType.OK)) {
                            
                            
                            pC.showOrderDetail();
                        }
                        //pC.menuGetTotal();//tinh sau
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }
    
    public void setQuantity() {
        spin = new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(1, 100, 0);
        quantity.setValueFactory(spin);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        setQuantity();
    }
    
}
```

ProductController :

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import com.mysql.cj.x.protobuf.MysqlxCrud.Column;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ProductController implements Initializable{
    @FXML
    private GridPane gridProd;

    @FXML
    private Button clBtn;

    @FXML
    private Button doneBtn;
 
    @FXML
    private Button clrBtn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<order_detailModel, String> colName;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<order_detailModel, String> colPrice;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<order_detailModel, String> colQuantity;
    
    @FXML
    private TableView<order_detailModel> orderView;
    
    @FXML
    private Button payBtn;

    @FXML
    private Button printBillBtn;

    @FXML
    private Label totalBill;
    
    @FXML 
    private Connection connection;
    private PreparedStatement prepare;
    private ResultSet result;
    private Alert alert;
    
    @FXML
    private Stage sideStage;
    private Scene scene;
    private Parent root;

    private int cID;
    public void customerID() throws SQLException {
         String sql = "SELECT MAX(cus_id) FROM customer";
         connection = Database.connect();
         
         try {
             prepare = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
             result = prepare.executeQuery();
             if (result.next()) {
                 cID = result.getInt("MAX(cus_id)");
             }
             String checkCID = "SELECT MAX(cus_id) FROM receipt";
             prepare = connection.prepareStatement(checkCID);
             result = prepare.executeQuery();
             int checkID = 0;
             if (result.next()) {
                 checkID = result.getInt("MAX(cus_id)");
             }
             if (cID == 0) {
                 cID += 1;
             } else if (cID == checkID) {
                 cID += 1;
             }
             data.cusId = cID;
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
    
    private String odID;
    public void order_detailID() throws SQLException {
     String sql = "SELECT MAX(ord_id) FROM order_detail";
        connection = Database.connect();
        
        try {
            prepare = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            result = prepare.executeQuery();
            if (result.next()) {
                odID = result.getString("MAX(ord_id)");
            }
            String checkODID = "SELECT MAX(ord_id) FROM receipt ";
            prepare = connection.prepareStatement(checkODID);
            result = prepare.executeQuery();
            String checkID = null;
            if (result.next()) {
                checkID = result.getString("MAX(ord_id)");
            }
            if (odID == null) {
                String aIM = "ORD-" + 0;
                odID = aIM + 1;
            } else if (odID == checkID) {
                String aIM = "ORD-" + 0;
                odID = aIM + 1;
            }
            data.ordDiD = odID;
            System.out.println(data.ordDiD);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
    

       private ObservableList<productModel> cardDataList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        
        public ObservableList<productModel> getData(){
            
            ObservableList<productModel> ListData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            
            String getData = "SELECT * FROM product";
            try {
                connection = Database.connect();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                prepare = connection.prepareStatement(getData);
                result = prepare.executeQuery();
                
                productModel productM;
                
                while(result.next()) {
                    productM = new productModel(result.getInt("id")
                                                ,result.getString("pro_id")
                                                , result.getString("pro_name")
                                                , result.getDouble("pro_price")
                                                , result.getInt("pro_quantity")
                                                , result.getString("pro_image"));
                    ListData.add(productM);
                }
            }catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return ListData;
        }
        
        public void menuProd() {
            cardDataList.clear();
            cardDataList.addAll(getData());
            
            int row = 0; 
            int column = 0;
            gridProd.getChildren().clear();
            gridProd.getRowConstraints().clear();
            gridProd.getColumnConstraints().clear();
            
            for(int i  = 0; i < cardDataList.size(); i++) {
                try {
                    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("cardProduct.fxml"));
                    Pane pane = loader.load();
                    CardProdController cpC = loader.getController();
                    cpC.setData(cardDataList.get(i));
                    
                    if(column == 3) {
                        column = 0;
                        row += 1;
                    }
                    
                    gridProd.add(pane, column++, row);
                    
                    GridPane.setMargin(pane, new Insets(10));
                }catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        
        public void clFcn(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
            
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("StaffSection.fxml"));
            sideStage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
            scene = new Scene(root);
            sideStage.setScene(scene);
            sideStage.setResizable(false);
            sideStage.show();
        }
        
        public void doneFcn(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
            
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("StaffSection.fxml"));
            sideStage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
            scene = new Scene(root);
            sideStage.setScene(scene);
            sideStage.setResizable(false);
            sideStage.show();
        }
        
        public ObservableList<order_detailModel> orderDList() throws SQLException {
               ObservableList<order_detailModel> oList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
               
               String getData = "SELECT pro_name, pro_price, pro_quantity FROM order_detail";
               connection = Database.connect();
               try {
                    prepare = connection.prepareStatement(getData);
                    result = prepare.executeQuery();
                    
                    order_detailModel ordDM;
                    while(result.next()) {
                        ordDM = new order_detailModel(result.getString("pro_name")
                                                        ,result.getDouble("pro_price")
                                                        ,result.getInt("pro_quantity"));
                        oList.add(ordDM);
                    }
               }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            return oList; 
        }
        
        ObservableList<order_detailModel> listOrdD;
        public void showOrderDetail() {
            try {
                
                listOrdD = orderDList();
                
                colName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("pro_name"));
                colPrice.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("pro_price"));
                colQuantity.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("pro_quantity"));
                
                orderView.setItems(listOrdD);
                
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                e.getMessage();
            }
        }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        getData();
        menuProd();
    }
}
```

FXML file use Productcontroller :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<BorderPane prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="1200.0" stylesheets="@CSS/TableServe.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/21" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.ProductController">
   <center>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <AnchorPane fx:id="acPane1" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="15.0" prefHeight="670.0" prefWidth="750.0">
               <children>
                  <ScrollPane layoutX="15.0" layoutY="15.0" prefHeight="640.0" prefWidth="720.0">
                     <content>
                        <GridPane fx:id="gridProd" hgap="10.0" prefHeight="879.0" prefWidth="680.0" vgap="10.0">
                          <columnConstraints>
                            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                          </columnConstraints>
                          <rowConstraints>
                            <RowConstraints fillHeight="false" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="100.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="100.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="100.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="100.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                          </rowConstraints>
                        </GridPane>
                     </content>
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                     </padding>
                  </ScrollPane>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
            <AnchorPane fx:id="acPane2" layoutX="785.0" layoutY="15.0" prefHeight="670.0" prefWidth="400.0">
               <children>
                  <Pane prefHeight="670.0" prefWidth="400.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                     <children>
                        <TableView fx:id="orderView" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="456.0" prefWidth="370.0">
                          <columns>
                            <TableColumn fx:id="colName" prefWidth="166.4000244140625" text="Name" />
                            <TableColumn fx:id="colPrice" prefWidth="108.800048828125" text="Price" />
                              <TableColumn fx:id="colQuantity" prefWidth="93.5999755859375" text="Quantity'" />
                          </columns>
                        </TableView>
                        <Button fx:id="payBtn" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="566.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="120.0" text="Pay" />
                        <Button fx:id="printBillBtn" layoutX="270.0" layoutY="566.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="120.0" text="Print BIll" />
                        <Button fx:id="clrBtn" layoutX="140.0" layoutY="566.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="120.0" text="Clear" />
                        <Button fx:id="clBtn" layoutX="225.0" layoutY="629.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#clFcn" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="160.0" text="Cancel" />
                        <Button fx:id="doneBtn" layoutX="17.0" layoutY="629.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#doneFcn" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="160.0" text="Done" />
                        <Label fx:id="totalBill" layoutX="17.0" layoutY="489.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="173.0" text="Total: 00$$">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="20.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                     </children>
                  </Pane>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

i did almost everything, using chatgpt got help ofc but still dont know why, i think it my sql is wrong ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The stack trace is pretty clear as to what the problem is: “`this.colName` is null”. Is there an element in the FXML that uses that controller with `fx:id=“colName”`?

Comment: *”using chatgpt got help ”*. All ChatGPT does is essentially take the most common code found on the internet in the context of the words used in your prompt. That includes code posted in questions and incorrect code. If there are common mistakes posted online, it will just replicate them. ChatGPT can be a useful timesaver but *only* when you are a good enough programmer to be able to judge whether the code it produces is correct or not. You are not at that point in your career yet.

Comment: yes the TableColumn i just update the fxml code

Comment: What is the FXML file's name? Doesn't `new ProductController()` initialize `colName` to `null`?

Comment: Please punctuate your text properly.  All these lower case i's drive me crazy :-)  Use [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/) or something like that - it is probably a better use of AI for you than ChatGPT generated code.  And ofc, use full words, not internet slang abbreviations.

Answer (score 3):

**Don't create controllers in code when the controller is specified in FXML**

*Never* call `new` on a controller that is specified by the `fx:controller` attribute in an FXML file.

This code is *wrong*:

```
ProductController pC = new ProductController();
```

For more info also see:

- [controller must be loaded (*not* instantiated)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36186907/javafx-label-null-pointer-exception)

**When you *can* create new controllers in code**

The only valid case to call `new` on a controller is if both of these are true:

- You will call [`setController`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#setController(java.lang.Object)) on the FXMLLoader *before* you load the FXML.

AND

- A controller is *not* specified in the FXML file being loaded.

However, you aren't doing any of these things.

From the documentation for `setController`:

> Sets the controller associated with the root object. The value passed to this method is used as the value of the `fx:controller` attribute. This method must be called prior to loading the document when using controller event handlers when an `fx:controller` attribute is not specified in the document.

For an example of setting controllers in code, see the section titled "Setting a Controller on the FXMLLoader" in this answer:

- [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml)

One scenario where you might want to set a controller in code is in conjunction with the `fx:root` construct as detailed in the Oracle tutorial:

- [Creating a Custom Control with FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/custom_control.htm)

**Common issues with creating new controllers in code**

Only the `FXMLLoader` will initialize the `@FXML` annotated fields in your controller to the values configured in your FXML file.  If you just create a new controller instance in your code, without also setting that controller instance on an FXMLLoader and calling `load()` to initialize the controller instance, then all of the `@FXML` annotated fields in the controller instance will be `null`.

Additionally, if you had *also* loaded the FXML elsewhere and that FXML referenced a controller like yours does, then when you loaded the FXML, the loader will have created an instance of the controller that you specified in the FXML.  So, if you then call `new` on the controller, you will get *another* instance of the controller, totally unrelated to the instance created by the `FXMLLoader` and to the object hierarchy that was returned by the [`load()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load()) method used.

**Alternate approaches**

Often when people create new controllers, what they should be doing instead is either:

- [Getting the controller](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#getController()) from the loader and using that.

OR

- Refactoring their code so that they don't need a controller reference at the place they are trying to use it (e.g. by [applying an MVC design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx)).

OR

- Setting the controller instance on the FXMLLoader, then asking the loader to `load()` an FXML (that does not have an `fx:controller` attribute).  That will initialize the controller instance that was created in the code.