# Difficulty Moving Multiple Circles Through JavaFx's GridPane

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane

I am currently facing challenges while working with GridPane. My objective is to move a specified number of generated circles through the cells of a GridPane. I have 5 GridPane and in every one of them consists of 10 vertical cells, and I aim to move the circles one cell at a time, starting from 0 and progressing until the last cell in every GridPane, where the circle should disappear.

I have successfully moved a single circle, but I'm encountering difficulties when handling multiple circles and orchestrating their movement in a sequential line. Additionally, I'm seeking guidance on adjusting the speed of the circles individually. I would like to incorporate a speed factor, so if there is a slow-moving circle, it will cause a delay in the overall movement of the line.

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
package phase1;

import javafx.animation.*;
import Classes.Person;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Phase1 extends Application {
    ArrayList<Circle> PEOPLE;
    private List<Circle> objects;
    private Timer timer;
    private boolean isRowEmpty(GridPane gridPane, int rowIndex) {
        for (javafx.scene.Node node : gridPane.getChildren()) {
            Integer nodeRowIndex = GridPane.getRowIndex(node);
            if (nodeRowIndex != null && nodeRowIndex.intValue() == rowIndex) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        // Create the root container (AnchorPane)
        Parent fxmlRoot = new FXMLLoader().load(getClass().getResource("/PHASE.fxml"));
        // Create the controller and move the circles
        Phase1Controller controller = new Phase1Controller();


        Group root = new Group(); //Creating a Group
        root.getChildren().add(fxmlRoot);
        GridPane graid1 = (GridPane) fxmlRoot.lookup("#Grid2");
        objects = new ArrayList<>();
        //PEOPLE = Phase1Controller.show_circles(fxmlRoot, 10);
        ArrayList<Person> people = Main1.generatePeople(5);
        Circle c1 = people.get(0).circle;
        Circle c2 = new Circle(22.5,Color.RED);

        timer = new Timer();
        graid1.add(c1,0,0);
        int RowIndex = 0;

        AtomicInteger rowIndex = new AtomicInteger(0);
        AtomicBoolean ss = new AtomicBoolean(true);
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    int currentRowIndex = rowIndex.getAndIncrement();
                    if (currentRowIndex >0){
                        //graid1.getChildren().set(currentRowIndex-1,c2);

                        }

                        // Add the node to the new row
                    graid1.getChildren().remove(c1);

                    // Add the node to the new row
                    graid1.add(c1, 0, currentRowIndex);
                    int pp = graid1.getRowConstraints().size();
                    System.out.println(pp);
                    if(pp == currentRowIndex){ graid1.getChildren().remove(c1); timer.cancel();}

                });


            }
        }, 0, 1000);// Run every 1 second




            // Create a scene and set it to the stage
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setTitle("Team 1");
        stage.setResizable(true); // Display the Resizable
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }


    }
```

And here is a gif from the GUI, illustrating only one circle in motion:

[image]

Comment: Create an [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean).

Comment: *"I'm encountering difficulties when handling multiple circles"* -> What is the difficulty?  Can you describe what the problem is (in words)?

Comment: The code provided doesn't compile on its own.  Provide something to reproduce the issue via copy and paste with no change or addition (and removing unused methods like `isRowEmpty`).  If you will use FXML in that, then provide the FXML and controller used, otherwise provide Java code that generates the missing parts of the scene graph.

Comment: Don't use a `java.util.Timer` for animation, use [JavaFX animation capabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60685975/1155209).  [Don't create a new controller in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77542904/cannot-invoke-javafx-scene-control-tablecolumn-setcellvaluefactoryjavafx-util/77546686#77546686) for a task like this.

Comment: Don't create variables you never use.  Most IDEs will have some way to show this, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587729/how-to-use-intellij-idea-to-find-all-unused-code), or they will just automatically highlight the unused code in the editor.   An IDE can also [indent code correctly for you](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html). Follow [naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

Comment: Also please, please stick to one question per question.  If you have other questions such as adjusting animation speed, then ask them as separate questions,

Answer (score 2):

You are asking more than one question. Keep your post at one question per post. Here is something that can maybe help you move your circles.

I would use `Timeline` over `Timer`.

**`Timeline` Example**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class Mavenproject3 extends Application {
    final int ROW_COUNT = 8;
    final int COLUMN_COUNT = 1;

    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage){
        
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.setGridLinesVisible(true);
        RowConstraints rowConstraints = new RowConstraints(100, 100, 100);
        ColumnConstraints columnConstraints = new ColumnConstraints(100, 100, 100);
        for(int i = 0; i < ROW_COUNT; i++)
        {
            gridPane.getRowConstraints().add(rowConstraints);
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i < COLUMN_COUNT; i++)
        {
            gridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(columnConstraints);
        }
        
        Circle c1 = new Circle(22.5,Color.BLUE);
        Circle c2 = new Circle(22.5,Color.RED);
        Circle c3 = new Circle(22.5,Color.YELLOW);
        Circle c4 = new Circle(22.5,Color.GREEN);
        Map<Circle, Integer> circleMap = new LinkedHashMap();        
        circleMap.put(c1, -1);
        circleMap.put(c2, -1);
        circleMap.put(c3, -1);
        circleMap.put(c4, -1);
        List<Circle> keys = new ArrayList(circleMap.keySet());
        
        AtomicInteger addCircleCounter = new AtomicInteger();
        AtomicInteger cycleCounter = new AtomicInteger();
        
        Timeline oneSecondsWonder = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), (ActionEvent event) -> {
            //Moving circles
            if(cycleCounter.get() > 0 && cycleCounter.get() < circleMap.size() + ROW_COUNT)
            {
                for(Circle key : keys)
                {
                    if(circleMap.get(key) > -1)
                    {
                        //System.out.println("Moving Circle " + key.getFill()+ " to " + circleMap.get(key));
                        if(circleMap.get(key) >= ROW_COUNT - 1 )
                        {
                            gridPane.getChildren().remove(key);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            circleMap.merge(key, 1, Integer::sum);
                            gridPane.getChildren().remove(key);                        
                            gridPane.add(key, 0, circleMap.get(key));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            //Add Circle to GridPane
            if(addCircleCounter.get()< circleMap.size())
            {
                //System.out.println("Add Circle " + keys.get(addCircleCounter.get()).getFill()+ " to GridPane!");
                gridPane.add(keys.get( addCircleCounter.get()), 0, 0);   
                circleMap.merge(keys.get( addCircleCounter.get()), 1, Integer::sum);
            }  
           
            cycleCounter.getAndIncrement();
            addCircleCounter.getAndIncrement();
        }));
        oneSecondsWonder.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        oneSecondsWonder.play();
        
        Button btnDecreaseSpeed = new Button("<");
        btnDecreaseSpeed.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            double rate = oneSecondsWonder.getRate();
            if (rate > 1) {
                oneSecondsWonder.setRate(oneSecondsWonder.getRate() - 1);
                System.out.println("Speed: " + oneSecondsWonder.getRate());
            }
        });
        
        Button btnIncreaseSpeed = new Button(">");
        btnIncreaseSpeed.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            double rate = oneSecondsWonder.getCurrentRate();
            if (rate < 10) {
                oneSecondsWonder.setRate(oneSecondsWonder.getRate() + 1);
                System.out.println("Speed: " + oneSecondsWonder.getRate());
            }
        });        
        
        VBox root = new VBox(gridPane, new HBox(btnDecreaseSpeed, btnIncreaseSpeed));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setTitle("Team 1");
        stage.setResizable(true); // Display the Resizable
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

**Edit**
Added Buttons to increase and decrease speed. Output not updated!

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I want every circle moves at a different speed. If one moves slower, it affects the movement of the circles behind it. The faster circles reach the end while the slower ones continue at their own pace until they also reach the end. I don't intend to add buttons to speed up the movement of all circles.

Comment: @Jam2002, As stated earlier and by a few other people, you should only ask one question at a time. It seems your original question was answered, maybe, and now you have turned this question into a moving question after each new answer. Take what you have learned here and do more research to incorporate your new requirements into your program. If you run continue to run into issues, come back with a new question.